# Entity reference content is disappeared

Tags: users, entities

I have a problem in viewing the content of an *Entity Reference* in a content type.
when I add a link of the *node* or an *Entity form* the content of it appears only in *admin* content type view , while it does not appear in the content type view of users of other *roles* such as *authenticated* users.
I searched in the permissions of the roles but nothing is related.
What is the problem? How can I fix it?

The content type I am creating called agenda
adding new content of type agenda
[image: adding new content of type agenda]

The new agenda is created
in this picture I am logged in as admin
the acceptance form and members fields are two Entity References, every thing is working fine and all fields are displayed
[image: every thing is working fine and all fields are displayed]

now I am logged in as "apahauo" authinticated user
the Acceptance form disappeared and the members field showing only "spahauo" while "stadirites" disappeared.
[image]

Comment: Please use the correct words to explain your problem. The words content type is creating some complexities because a content type refers to node form that is not shown to every user by default.

Comment: content types like article or Basic page, i created I new one e.g news and I added a field of type entity reference refers to an a form created as Entityform type. However the form appears only to admin but not other users.

Comment: Clearly explain so you want to to show links Content or in Content type?

Comment: i want to show links content in Content type. it is shown for admin but not for other users.

Comment: can you post your screenshot?

Comment: Keep in mind, the content will normally need to be published (status=1) to be viewed by authenticated users. Also, if the user can't see the user entity reference, it might be because they don't have the 'view user profiles' permission.

Comment: your instructions helped and every thing is working fine now !!